# Locate First Error Name in Exception Object

Tags: exception

I see message like this `Insert failed. First exception on row 0; First error: SOME_NAME_OF_ERROR`

I want to get this message in `catch` block and store it in variable, for example:

`String ErrorName = ??? ;`

And then I want to check this like that:

`if(ErrorName == 'SOME_NAME_OF_ERROR') { ... } else { ... }`

How to get this Error Name?

Comment: there is a method `getCause` in exception class. I guess you could use this

Answer (score 1):

Errors are thrown by your code, so you knew that what exceptions thrown by your code. E.g: If two messages like `message 1` or `message 2` has thrown and you need to catch them, then you write catch block in following mode:

`catch(Exception e)
{
    if(e.getMessage().contains('message 1') {...}
    else if(e.getMessage().contains('message 2') {...}
}`

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

DML operations generally throws `DMLException` which can be catched in catch block.

For eg.

```
catch(DMLException ex){
 String msg=ex.getMessage();
}
```

Generally a hierarchy of catch block is more suitable to identify the type of exception properly.Like this:

```
catch(DMLException ex){
//some operation
}
catch(Exception ex){
//some operation
}
```

In this hierarchical approach `Exception` type must be catched in last catch block.

You can leverage the benifit of other methods of [Exception](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm) class and can use them according to your need.